# Get string from html with Regex

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, regex, windows-phone-8

I have HTML with this code inside:

```
    <div id="div_space">
    <div id="div" class="SCREENONLY" itemprop="description">Baby you<br />
    abcdefghijklmnop123456789</div><div id="song" class="PRINTONLY">blabla</div>
```

And i want to parse `abcdefghijklmnop123456789` from the html with `Regex`:

```
string str = "<div id=ֿ\"div_spaceֿ\">(.*?)</div>"
Regex regex = new Regex(str);
Match match = regex.Match(html);
```

And Match is always empty, any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/34397

Comment: Use [HTML Agility Pack](htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AS Slaks commented you can get help of library like [Html Agile pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to do this task

```
var dives = from div in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
           where div.Id == "div_space" 
           select div;
```